# Валидация [input type="number"] на разное количество символов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, валидация

Есть форма, в ней несколько input.
Один из них имеет тип number и предназначен для ввода ИНН длиной 10 или 12 символов.
Как можно делать валидацию этого поля?
Прописал в теге input
    `pattern="^(\d{10}|\d{12})$"`, но не работает, форма отправляется при любом количестве введённых цифр. В чем ошибка или может стоит делать как то с использованием jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось реализовать следующим образом, может кому-то будет полезно.

```
    function validateINN() {
    var inn_length = $("#inn").val().length;
    var inn_input = document.querySelector("#inn");
    if (inn_length != 0) {
        if ((inn_length == 10) || (inn_length == 12)) {
            inn_input.setCustomValidity("");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            inn_input.setCustomValidity("Введите в поле ИНН 10-ти или 12-ти значный номер, либо оставьте поле пустым");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        inn_input.setCustomValidity("");
        return true;
    }
}
```